# HTTPs by default

Tags: discussion, ssl, security

I am not sure how I missed this before, but when navigating to SO or other SE sites, it does not use HTTPs by default. Has this always been the case?

Why does the site not redirect to HTTPs immediately? Would it not be more secure for SE users?

Comment: HTTPS is not yet fully supported (`https://meta.<sitename>.stackexchange.com` urls have the wrong certificate, for example).

Comment: See http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/ for a status report on why it is taking a while.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Whoa, that article is two years old already! Thanks for the info though.